# How to call API with multiple parameters from .NET Core MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to write .NET Core MVC project which will call existing API and retrieve some data. For an API post call which needed only one parameter I wrote following code:

```
public async Task<GenericResultType<string>> CallValidate(string url, string sessionId)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId))
                request.Content = new StringContent(sessionId, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            else
                throw new BaseException<PublicWebExceptions>(PublicWebExceptions.SessionIdNullOrEmpty);

            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GenericResultType<string>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                if (result != default)
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }

            throw new BaseException<PublicWebExceptions>(PublicWebExceptions.InvalidCall);
        }
```

My question is, is this a valid way and how do I call a post method with multiple string parameters, for example if I had string sessionId and string code, how do I pass both of them to API.

Comment: How the API expects the parameters to be passed? In JSON body or in querystring ? How did you try passing multiple parameters? Did that approach work?

Comment: API expects parameters as a queryString

Comment: Since you are using Core MVC, why not use a model to hold those 2 values, and create a form on your view? 

There are lots of ways. Making an AJAX call is another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add multiple parameters as a querystring,you can do like this:

```
string newUrl=url+"?sessionId="+sessionId+"&&code="+"codedata";
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, newUrl);
```